# Dynamic Carosel images not showing with ngFor (Angular 7)

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, carousel, ngfor

I am setting up a carousel for showing dynamic images fetching from an Node API. I am using ngFor directive in Angular 7

Here is my code that i have tried:

TypeScript:

```
getPromotions() {
    this.dashboardService.getPromotions()
      .subscribe(res => {

          this.promotions = res.listings.map(res => {
            return {image: `data:${
              res.file_mime_type
              };base64,${this.dashboardService.bufferToString(res.file_content.data)}`}
            });


        console.log('Promotions::', this.promotions);

      }, err => {

      })
  }
```

html:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <ngb-carousel>
            <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let promotion of promotions">
                <img [src]="promotion.image" height="392" class="d-block w-100" alt="Random slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>No Promotion</h3>
                    <p>There is not active Promotion.</p>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </ngb-carousel>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code should show the images in promotions array but it showing nothing.

Comment: Meaby `ngb-carousel` load templates only on init, when there is no data inside `this.promotions`?

Comment: @PatrykUszyński i have tried with image with index 0 in the promotions array. and It showing that image. but problem with this for loop i think

Comment: same issue. did u find any solution @NabeelAhmadKhan